# How many times does "Hammer of the Gods" deal extra damage?

Tags: dnd-4e, powers

The Cleric level 3 Encounter Power **Hammer of the Gods**[<sup>DDI</sup>](http://www.wizards.com/dndinsider/compendium/power.aspx?id=7085) (Divine Power) states:

> **Hit**: 1[W] + Strength modifier radiant damage. When any ally hits the target before the start of your next turn, the target takes 1d6 extra radiant damage.

Usually these powers are a bit more specific, like "the first time an ally hits the target..." or "each time an ally hits the target..." but this just provides a rather vague "when any ally hits the target..."

How many times does this power deal an extra 1d6 radiant damage?

If a ranger used Twin Strike and hit twice, would Hammer of the Gods trigger twice and provide 2d6 radiant damage?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Hammer of the Gods can trigger any number of times**

As you note, unlike many powers Hammer of the Gods does not limit its self to only the first hit.

So, yes, this synergies nicely with a power like Twin Strike